# Why is this substitution not valid?

Tags: integration

I can't seem to notice the mistake in this calculation:
$$\int(5+\cos t)\sin t\:dt=-\int(5+\cos t)\:d(5+\cos t)=-\frac{1}{2}(5+\cos t)^2+k$$
I would argue I did nothing illegal because
$$d(5+\cos t)=-\sin t\:dt$$
and definitely because
$$\frac{d}{dt}\Big(-\frac{1}{2}(5+\cos t)^2+k\Big)=-(5+\cos t)(-\sin t)=(5+\cos t)\sin t$$
Yet I receive another answer from my professor's notes and from Wolfram Alpha, which I do find to be very reliable sources.

Comment: What different answer did you receive on wolfram alpha?

Comment: Note that, because of trigonometric identities, there may be several equivalent way to express the same antiderivative. For example, it is also equal to $-5\cos(t)-\cos(2t)/4+C$.

Comment: $$-\frac{1}{2}(\cos t)(\cos t+10)$$

Comment: They are actually the same, as $k$ swallows in your constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The substitution is totally valid, no doubt about it.

The answer that you have received on wolfram alpha has *just differed by a constant* from your result since it is an indefinite integral that we are talking about.

If you carefully observe, the result you obtained on wolfram alpha can be expressed as:
$$-\frac{1}{2}\cos t (\cos t+10)$$
$$=\color{red}{-\frac{1}{2}\cos^2 t - 5 \cos t}$$

Just that the above result does not contain the constant of integration $k'$(say). But it should since it is an indefinite integral.

And your result can now be rewritten as:
$$-\frac{1}{2}(5+\cos t)^2+k$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}(25+10\cos t+ \cos^2 t)+k$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\cos^2 t - 5 \cos t +(- \frac{25}{2}+k)$$
$$=\color{red}{-\frac{1}{2}\cos^2 t - 5 \cos t} + \color{blue}{k'}$$

So you see, the results are just the same differing by a mere constant.

Comment: @A.Y. You're welcome.